# Want headers to appear on subsequent pages

Tags: fancyhdr

I have the table of contents for Tables and Figures. The headers in the figures pages are working fine. However, in the table pages, they are not.
Here is the code in driver.tex

```
\tableofcontents
% This puts the word "Page" right justified above everything else.
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill Page\par}
% Asking LaTeX for a new page here guarantees that the LOF is on a separate page
% after the TOC ends.
\clearpage
\newpage
% Making the LOT and LOF "parts" rather than chapters gets them indented at
% level -1 according to the chart: top of page 4 of the document at
% ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{LIST OF TABLES}
\addtocontents{toc}{CHAPTER \par}
\renewcommand{\cftlabel}{Table}
\addtocontents{lot}{Table~\hfill Page \par}
\listoftables
% This gets the headers for the LOT right on the first page.  Subsequent pages
% are handled by the fancyhdr code in the asudis.sty file.
\clearpage
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\addtocontents{toc}{CHAPTER \par}
\renewcommand{\cftlabel}{Figure}
% This gets the headers for the LOF right on the first page.  Subsequent pages
% are handled by the fancyhdr code in the asudis.sty file.
\addtocontents{lof}{Figure~\hfill Page \par}
\listoffigures
```

And here is the part in asudis.sty

```
% Get the header on subsequent pages right.
\renewcommand{\@cfttocstart}{
   \newgeometry{top=1.0in,hmargin=1.25in,height=9.0in,
   includehead,includefoot,letterpaper}%,showcrop,showframe}

   \doublespace
   \pagestyle{fancyplain}
   \afterpage{\lhead{\cftlabel}\rhead{Page}}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you could post what we refer to as a minimal working example. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) It allows us to copy-and-paste-and-compile your code and see exactly what you're seeing. It also makes it easy if it replicates your behaviour, without much effort to tweak the code as needed. Can you do that?